# C# multithreading on net 2, firebird database cancel and restart, how?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, firebird, .net-2.0

In winform app, I have `DataGridView` and thread which is loading data from database when user press button.

This loading is done on another thread, I don't know how to make the following scenario:

when user press another button, the same procedure starts, with different query, cancelling previous thread and loading data only from second time.

Currently it works in such way, that `DataGridView` is populated with second query, but after few seconds its repopulated with first query. And it shouldn't, first query should be in some way cancelled.

How to do that?

Comment: do not start the first query if you do not need its result

Comment: its written as example. If some user by mistake clicks not correct button, he have t owait unti datagrid popullates with more than 100k rows without option to break it and reload with correct query?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows what you are currently doing. If you can't cancel the query itself, then you should write your update code in such a way that your code doesn't update the grid once it has been 'cancelled'.

Comment: Depends upon how exactly you populate the grid. Typically, if you code it yourself, it is some `i++` loop, that keeps pulling the rows from some `rowset` and copy the values into some `Grid->Rows[i]->Column[j]->Value`. Then you just `break` out of the loop. If you use some more high-level libraries, then it typically has this loop inside and is loading/caching the data on demand, by some packets (no human would actually see more than 100 rows on the screen at one time, so no point to pull further rows unless human user actually starts scrolling). Those libs have their own means to `break` loop

Answer (score 1):

Below is a basic example how you can achieve the desired behavior. There is no cancelling database query, but there is ignoring results that is not relevant anymore.

```
public static IEnumerable<Row> GetRowsForTheFirstButton()
{
    var token = GridResultsSync.GetCurrentToken();

    // retrieving data
    ...

    if (GridResultsSync.IsTokenRelevant(token))
        return result;
    return null;
}
// exactly the same code for the second method
public static IEnumerable<Row> GetRowsForTheSecondButton()
{
    var token = GridResultsSync.GetCurrentToken();

    // retrieving data
    ...

    if (GridResultsSync.IsTokenRelevant(token))
        return result;

    return null;
}

...
class GridResultsSync
{
    static int _count = 0;
    public static int GetCurrentToken()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    }
    public static bool IsTokenRelevant(int token)
    {
        var currentCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        return currentCount - token  <=  2;
    }
}
```

When you call `GetRowsForTheFirstButton()` and `GetRowsForTheSecondButton()` then you  check if the result is not `null`, then you bind the result to grid, if the result is null then do nothing.

If you really want to cancel a query to DB then you may consider a little more complex approach. It can be done using [SqlCommand.Cancel Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel?view=netframework-4.7.2) or if you are using `Entity Framework` you can use [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).